# How can I install SolrClient with hhvm?

Tags: php, solr, hhvm

I'm trying to migrate from php5-fpm to hhvm service.

But the [document here](http://docs.hhvm.com/manual/en/solr.installation.php) says  `This extension is not available in HHVM yet`

Is there any workaround? I couldn't find anything useful on google.

Answer (score 0):

One possible workaround is to find pure PHP implementation of needed extension or protocol and make interface-compatible adapter to adopt in your code. For SolrClient [Solarium](https://github.com/solariumphp/solarium) looks promising. Usually extensions work faster than PHP code, but in case of HHVM difference may be neglected by overall performance boost.

Another approach is to give a try to [Zend Extension Source Compatibility Layer](https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/tree/master/hphp/runtime/ext_zend_compat), but either documentation and compatibility are rather limited, so it won't be easy.